# GIT not cloning on FreeBSD?

Tags: git, freebsd

I'm running a FreeBSD 8.2 server with GIT 1.7.4.1

Attempting to clone anything, like

```
$ git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git node
```

ends up, quickly, giving me this

```
Cloning into node...
```

and the only thing in the directory is this file

```
$ git-remote-https.core
```

(My above example is for node.js, but I get the same results for anything on GitHub)

Any clues as to why the repo isn't being cloned for me?? No error messages, just that file, which I have no idea what it is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git-remote-https.core` is the memory of the git-remote-https process at the time it crashed.  Yes, it crashed.  Why is anybody's guess.

I would suggest recompiling GIT from ports and trying that.  If it still crashes then I would recommend recompiling from ports but with `gdb` enabled, then you can use gdb to examine the core dump (as that file is known) to see where and why it crashed.

It may be an incompatibility between library versions, in which case compiling from ports usually fixes it, or it may be something more serious.

Answer (score 6):

Upgrading curl and openssl fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

If this starts happening immediately after a `portupgrade -a` or equivalent that upgraded git or openssl, try recompiling libcurl (e.g. `portupgrade -f curl`).

Answer (score 0):

No need to guess check on core:
http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/debugging.html